# Activity that calls finish after being started from onContextItemSelected ends initial activity?

Tags: android, contextmenu

Activity_A calls Activity_B (startActivity() and when _B calls finish(); both activities close.  I'm adding FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, I tried using startActivityForResult without any luck.

Activity_A is a TabActivity
Activity_B is an Activity

Activity_B is being called from Activity_A like:

```
            public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
              // code removed...
              Intent mViewIntent = new Intent(Activity_A.this, Activity_B.class);
              mViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
              mViewIntent.putExtra("ID", MY_IDS.get(position));
              this.startActivity(mViewIntent);
              // code removed...
            }
```

I know that when I call the same routine from within onItemClick() everything works as I expect, a new activity is started for Activity_B, if finish() is called or the user presses back, the program returns to Activity_A.  It seems that from within onContextItemSelected() the flag for new_task is being ignored or something else is wrong that I'm not understanding.  Please help me figure out this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my understanding of your problem goes, I do not see why you should use `mViewIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`.

See the [documentation for FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

Comment: Activity_B is an activity to edit the item selected on Activity_A, I tried without this code and clicking Save on Activity_B still causes _A to close.

It works just fine when I call the same code from onItemClick vs. onContextItemSelected.

Comment: Maybe some of your other code in the `onContextItemSelected` method causes ActivityA to exit. Thereby it looks like ActivityB`s finish() causes ActivityA to finish.

Comment: EXACTLY! Somehow when merging activities into the TabActivity I missed a finish() at the bottom of a very long block of code.  Originally I was starting _B and upon finish of _B I was calling another activity instead of returning.  I overlooked the finish in _A for 3 hours today.  That you for pointing me back to look again!  I felt like I was overlooking something so simple!